# How to get index and value in tuple through for loops in python in an elegant way?

Tags: python

I want to use every element with its index in a tuple.
I tried several ways but to write this code.

```
a = (1,2,3,0,0,1,2)
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(f"{i}th {a[i]}")
```

I don't want to use range(len(a)) when writing for loops in python ;)
is there any other elegant way?

Comment: use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate):`for i, val in enumerate(a): print(f"{i}th {val}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    print(f"{i}th {x}")
```